# Gunicorn NameError: global name 'fileno' is not defined

Tags: django, gunicorn

I'm working on a Django app with gunicorn right now.  Everything has been working for the past couple months but today, when I tried to deploy my latest changes to my dev server, I got this error when I tried to access it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ctaylor/.virtualenvs/seniordating/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 130, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/Users/ctaylor/.virtualenvs/seniordating/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 174, in handle_request
    resp.write_file(respiter)
  File "/Users/ctaylor/.virtualenvs/seniordating/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 396, in write_file
    if not self.sendfile(respiter):
  File "/Users/ctaylor/.virtualenvs/seniordating/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 360, in sendfile
    offset = os.lseek(fileno, 0, os.SEEK_CUR)
NameError: global name 'fileno' is not defined
```

Gunicorn command:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --pythonpath server base.wsgi_django:application
```

I have been unable to find anything about this online and have absolutely no idea what I did to cause this error. If anyone has any ideas, please let me know!

**UPDATE**

When running my server in debug mode, I get this error instead, and it shows up many more times:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ctaylor/.virtualenvs/seniordating/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/ctaylor/.virtualenvs/seniordating/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 54, in serve
    fullpath = os.path.join(document_root, newpath)
  File "/Users/ctaylor/.virtualenvs/seniordating/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 77, in join
    elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Comment: Have you checked you `settings.py` file? `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: What would I be checking for? I haven't updated those files in some time

Comment: This could be a project/environment problem instead of Guinicorn problem. Can you run it with simple server -> `./manage.py runserver`?

Comment: I can, that works fine

Comment: I see the same issue with gunicorn 19.4.4. I rolled back to 19.4.1 and the issue went away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm having the exact same issue with a Flask app. Turns out it is a bug in Gunicorn 19.4.4. Downgrading to 19.4.3 solves the problem for me.

Reporting it upstream.

Comment: It's fixed in 19.4.5